# hide a part of an iframe in ipad and iphones

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, iframe

I need to hide 300px from the top in an iframe. I have tried to hide it with overflow: hidden in css, but it's not working in an iphone or an ipad. How can I solve that?

My HTML-code

```
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
  <div class="iframe-content">
    <iframe src="http://my_url" width="940" height="900" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.iframe-wrapper {
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 940px; 
    height: 600px;
}
.iframe-content {
    position: absolute; 
    top: -300px;
}
```

Comment: have you tried giving `.iframe-content` a width and a height equal to the iframe inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a demo from your code and along with my suggestion it seems to be working:

html:

```
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
  <div class="iframe-content">
      <iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="400" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.iframe-wrapper {
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px;
    border: 5px solid orange;
    margin: 20px;
    background: red;
}

.iframe-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: -300px;
}

iframe { background: blue; }
```

**Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/MteRS/**

I changed the widths/heights so it would fit into the jsfiddle output panel a bit better.